# Any options available to set objects relative to canvas center point instead of top and left in FabricJS

Tags: javascript, angular, fabricjs

I have an issue on mobile orientation change. When the orientation changes the canvas size adjust himself accordingly. And objects in the canvas exist in the same position after orientation where they were before the orientation relatively the canvas left and top.

It will be more clear in the image.
[image]

I want to change the positions of the objects on window:resize relatively to the center of canvas instead of left and top. Please help!

Comment: hi @fawad-mukhtar, can you please make an active snippet with a canvas and some objects? is so much easier to answer having basic reproducible context.

Answer (score 0):

You can center the object on canvas with `canvas.centerObject(object);`.

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

var dia1 = new fabric.Circle({
  radius: 12,
  left: 0,
  top: 0,
  originX: 'center',
  originY: 'center',
  fill: 'transparent',
  strokeWidth: 5,
  stroke: "red",
  width: 50,
  height: 50,
});
var dia2 = new fabric.Circle({
  radius: 5,
  left: 0,
  top: 0,
  originX: 'center',
  originY: 'center',
  fill: 'red',
  width: 50,
  height: 50,
});
var targetEl = new fabric.Group([dia1, dia2], {
  originX: 'center',
  originY: 'center',
});

//center object on canvas
canvas.centerObject(targetEl);
canvas.add(targetEl);
canvas.renderAll();

//center on window resize
$(window).resize(function() {
  canvas.centerObject(targetEl);
  canvas.renderAll();
});
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/3.4.0/fabric.js"></script>

<canvas id="c" width="600" height="300"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

you may need to set the object dimensions as follwing

```
const canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
// you can simply use 
canvas.viewportCenterObject(obj);
// or if you want to center manually
const centerObject = obj => {
  const center = canvas.getCenter();
  const zoom = canvas.getZoom();
  canvas.centerObject(obj);
  obj.set({
    left:  center.left / zoom - obj.width / 2,
    top:  center.top / zoom - obj.height / 2,
  });
  obj.setCoords();
  canvas.calcOffset();
  canvas.renderAll()
};
```